# Lexicographical order

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Hello everyone i'm trying to solve an exercise that contains the following istructions.

Let it be $ \Bbb R^n = \{ x = (x_1, ..., x_n) : x_1, ..., x_n \in \Bbb R \}.$
Let define on $ \Bbb R^n$ a relation $<$ as below:
for $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$ and $ x<y$ if, and only if exists a j $\in \{1,..,n \}$ with $(x_j<y_j)$
and for all i $ \in \Bbb N$ with $(i<j \to x_i=y_i).$

And what do the above istructions mean?

Comment: Um, what is the question...?

Comment: The question is missing here.

Comment: So, if $A=(2.1,2.1,2.1,3,2.7,0.5)$ and $B=(2.1,2.1,2.1,5,1.3,7)$, then $A<B$? And $j=4$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: I edited the post and added the question at the end of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

This ordering is the same as the one that orders words in a dictionary. What makes a word come before another (of the same length) in the dictionary? Well that happens exactly when at the first place the two words differ, the word that comes first has a letter that comes before the other word's letter in the underlying alphabet.

Same thing here: we start with an order on $\mathbb{R}$, our 'alphabet', and then declare that a sequence, or 'word', of $n$ reals, or 'letters', comes before another if at the first place where the sequences differ, the first word's letter comes before the second's in the alphabet.

So for example when $n=3$, $(1,1,1)<(1,1,2)<(1,1,2.1)<(1,2,-5)<(1,2,1000)<(700,3,-13)$ etc., and when $n=4$, $(-3,4,4,1)<(-3,4,5,-6)<(-3,4,5,-5)$.

Comment: what confused me, was the notation of $\forall i  \in \Bbb N (i<j \to x_i=y_i).$ As $i<j \to x_i=y_i$ means: whatever i $\in \Bbb N$ is,  $\iff i<j$ all couples' components $(x_i,y_i)$ are ever each other the same, or it could be that they are same and/or different???

Comment: @CAFosta I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: *updated question*: Are $\forall i \in \Bbb N, i<j \in \{1,..,n\}$ and $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, for example j=n, $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})$) always equal (I mean $(x_1,y_1)=...=(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})$), or could it be they differ?

Comment: @CAFosta I again don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry. From *updated question* substitude $(x_1=y_1),...,(x_n=y_n)$ to $(x_1,y_1)=...=(x_n,y_n)$.

Comment: @CAFosta If $j=n$, then yes, $x_1=y_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}=y_{n-1}$ and $x_{n} < y_{n}$